# Confused on picking best search engine

Tags: mysql, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine

Currently I am using custom made Java search engine. This Java engine uses Lucene to index MySql records. The are several problems with search engine:

1- Search results are not accurate.

2- It do not use weighting algorithms to make most matching result on top.

3- It consumes lot of memory.

4- Very hard to maintain, for various reasons.

So what I need to do is use ready made search engine either commercial or open source, that could integrate with my system smoothly and resolve my problems (as much as possible).

Could you please give me options, and where to look.

Thanks,
Wa'el

Comment: submit your site to google (at this moment, google is the champ)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/):

> Solr is the popular, blazing fast open source enterprise search platform from the Apache Lucene project. Its major features include powerful full-text search, hit highlighting, faceted search, dynamic clustering, database integration, and rich document (e.g., Word, PDF) handling. Solr is highly scalable, providing distributed search and index replication, and it powers the search and navigation features of many of the world's largest internet sites.

Note that many of your problems might be due to misconfiguration or wrong queries, rather than lucene not being good.

Comment: yes, however luence is indeed require lots of memory,and try to keep your collection small (as in smaller doc size), dun just anyhow index from column A to Z

Comment: Solr works quite nicely out of the box. You can use the DataImportHandler for MySQL integration. If you have more difficulties, you can ask more specific questions both here and in the Solr mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

While I too like Solr, I suggest you also consider [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/). It is said to be very easily integrated with MySQL. I would try Solr first and, if it does not help, try Sphinx as the second option.

Comment: Yeah Sphinx in quite nice, but it also crashes very regulary!